# Date Time conversion/ Date diff in SSRS

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services, casting

I have an SSRS report where I am using below query.
(This query works fine in SQL server, problem is only in SSRS report)
    --DECLARE @Range Number = 10;
    SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE
    USERNAME = 'MIKE'
    AND
       (
            @Range = '10'
            and
            Convert(datetime, MyDate, 120) <= GETDATE()
        )
        or
        (
            @Range IN ('20','30') 
            and
            DATEDIFF(DD, Convert(datetime, MyDate, 120) , GETDATE()) <= @Range
        )

Unfortunately the myDate Column coming from database is a varchar column.

The SSRS throws an out-of-range exception.

Then I tried converting Getdate to `Convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 120)`  and compare with myDate (without conversion as myDate is already in YYYY-MM-DD format but as a varchar in database)it still throws error. I assume this time coz SSRS is not able to process datediff in varchar columns.

When I run these queries individually, it works fine. i.e -

```
Declare @Range Number = 10;
Select * from tbl1 
where username = 'MIKE' and 
(
@Range = '10'
and 
convert(datetime, MyDate, 120) <= getdate()
```

Has anyone faced similar issue in SSRS ???

Comment: Why are you using format "103" if the varchar value is stored as YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was using 120. Modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE
USERNAME = 'MIKE'
AND
   (
        @Range = '10'
        and
        cast(myDate as datetime) <= GETDATE()
    )
    or
    (
        @Range IN ('20','30') 
        and
        cast(myDate as datetime) , GETDATE()) <= @Range
    )
```

Comment: Again says : Conversion of a varchar datatype to datetime data type resulted in an out of range value.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your problem is that some values of `myDate` are not in the correct format.  If you are using a more recent version of SQL Server, the function `try_convert()` can be a big help.

The reason it is failing is because of your logic.  The second condition after the `or` is looking at all records, not just Mike's.  I think you intend for the `where` clause to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1 WHERE
WHERE USERNAME = 'MIKE' AND
      ((@Range = '10' and Convert(datetime, MyDate, 120) <= GETDATE()
       ) or
       (@Range IN ('20','30') and
        DATEDIFF(DD, Convert(datetime, MyDate, 120) , GETDATE()) <= @Range
       )
      );
```

Note the extra set of parentheses.  Now, this will probably help for this particular query for `MIKE`.  But it won't help overall.  Finding the value(s) that fail conversion can be daunting.  If you are lucky, they fail easily.  You can look for them with starting with:

```
select MyDate
from tbl1
where MyDate not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]%';
```

If you are lucky, then this will find the offending values.  Otherwise, you'll have to dive more deeply into the date formats, looking at the particular month and day (and potentially hour, minute, and second) values.

Moral:  Store dates as dates.  Don't store them as `varchar()`.

Comment: I know it should have been in date format. It is someone else's code and I am suffering. thanks for response, will try suggested options.

Comment: Just to add, my query works fine in SQL. It is giving problem only in SSRS Report.

Comment: @user1820973 . . . You seem to have a problem in the values in `MyDate`.  The fact the query works sometimes but not others is just a question of which rows SQL Server attempts the conversion on.